# Are Bud and Tippi Dink actually D.I.N.K.'s?

Tags: character, animation, doug

[Bud](https://doug.fandom.com/wiki/Bud_Dink) and [Tippi](https://doug.fandom.com/wiki/Tippi_Dink) Dink are the next door neighbors of [Doug Funnie](https://doug.fandom.com/wiki/Doug_Funnie) on the show [*Doug*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_(TV_series)). A claim has recently come to my attention that the Dink's are so named because Dink is also an acronym [D.I.N.K.](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dinks.asp) meaning "Dual/Double Income No Kids". Essentially two working adults, typically married, who have no kids and therefore a large disposable income. The Dink's do fit this motif, always buying gadgets that Bud usually describes as "very expensive".

However, a dink [can also be](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dink#h70061866562920) "a stupid or contemptible person (used typically of a man)". Now Mr. Dink isn't stupid nor contemptible per se, but can come off as quite aloof and not all there sometimes (although he does offer Doug great advice and teachable moments).

*Doug* originally aired in the early 1990's, and I am not sure how long the acronym has been in popular use (the dictionary source does claim 1980's origin).

**So my question: is it verifiable that the "Dink = D.I.N.K." is true?** I would be looking for a quote from a member of the production staff or similar "canon" source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decider.com did an [interview](https://decider.com/2016/06/15/the-oral-history-of-nicktoons-part-ii-doug/) with the cast and crew of *Doug* where in the creator Jim Jinkins confirms the origin of Mr. Dink's name:

> I did not have a neighbor as fun as Mr. Dink. It was just a fun thing to add to the universe. **His last name came from the acronym: Double Income, No Kids.**
>
> <sub>*The Oral History Of ‘Nicktoons’, Part II: The Charming ‘Doug’ Embraced The Everyday Acts Of Adolescence*, By Caseen Gaines and Mathew Klickstein
> June 15, 2016 at 9:00am</sub>